# Add Xfce Group to REHL 6.6

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, xfce, desktop

I want to install Xfce on my REHL 6.6 (currently I think it uses Gnome2 and Compiz) but `yum grouplist` does not provide me any kind of Xfce group after I run

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Is there an other way to install it beside of `yum groupinstall xfce` ?

Comment: Do you get the same result from `yum grouplist` after running `yum clean all` ?  (Xfce shows in my grouplist on RHEL 6)

Comment: I have a cooperate version with a reduced package list. That's why I don't have it by default

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of `yum groupinfo Xfce` (see below), you should be able to run:

```
yum install Thunar xfce-utils xfce4-panel xfce4-session xfce4-settings xfconf xfdesktop xfwm4 NetworkManager-gnome Terminal gdm leafpad openssh-askpass orage polkit-gnome thunar-archive-plugin thunar-volman tumbler xfce4-appfinder xfce4-icon-theme xfce4-mixer xfce4-power-manager xfce4-session-engines xfwm4-theme-nodoka xfwm4-themes
```

Output from `yum groupinfo`:

```
$ yum groupinfo Xfce
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhui-lb, security
Setting up Group Process

Group: Xfce
 Description: A lightweight desktop environment that works well on low end machines.
 Mandatory Packages:
   Thunar
   xfce-utils
   xfce4-panel
   xfce4-session
   xfce4-settings
   xfconf
   xfdesktop
   xfwm4
 Default Packages:
   NetworkManager-gnome
   Terminal
   gdm
   leafpad
   openssh-askpass
   orage
   polkit-gnome
   thunar-archive-plugin
   thunar-volman
   tumbler
   xfce4-appfinder
   xfce4-icon-theme
   xfce4-mixer
   xfce4-power-manager
   xfce4-session-engines
   xfwm4-theme-nodoka
 Optional Packages:
   xfwm4-themes
 Conditional Packages:
   pinentry-gtk
```